# Pop Up with <a href=#modal> in java script

Tags: javascript, php, popup

i have code :

```
<div id="modal" style="display:none">
 <?php $name = $_GET['name']; echo $name; ?> 
</div>

$sql = mysql_query(SELECT * FROM data);
while($data = mysql_fecth_row($sql)){
 echo "<a href=\"#modal?name=".$data[0]."\" id=\"modal_id\">name</a>;
}
```

this popup not show, but if I delete `"?name=".$data[0]"` this popup show but `"$name"` is empty.

how to this popup show and the `"$data[0]"` include in `#modal`..?

thanks

Comment: You can refer https://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Comment: i can't understand.. :'(

Answer (score 0):

That's because, here is what a url should end with:

And you are making it:

```
file.php#id?parameter=value
```

And what you should have done is:

```
<div id="modal" style="display:none">
 <?php
  $sql = mysql_query(SELECT * FROM data);
  $data = mysql_fecth_row($sql);
  echo $data[0];
 ?> 
</div>
<a href="#modal" id="modal_id">name</a>
```